# jquery Malsup's form plugin and Ketchup validation to work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm having lots of problems getting the 2 plugins to work together...

heres the script i'm currently using, which doesn't work... it submits the form without validation...

```
   <script>
function validate() { 
$('#contact_form').ketchup();
}

function showResponse() { 
$('#form_content').html('thanks you for submitting the form');
}


$(document).ready(function() { 

$('#contact_form').ajaxForm( {
beforeSubmit: validate, 
success:  showResponse
} ); 

}); 
</script>
```

if i add a 'return false' in the validate function then the ketchup validation is triggered and the form is correctly validated, but even if it passes validation it doesn't submit.

anyone got any suggestions for how to get these 2 scripts to play nice together?

cheers

dog

Comment: you might wanna check your error console for any errors!

Comment: no, no errors... its basically all working correctly, its my implementation thats at fault... it looks to me (and i'm pretty rubbish at javascript) that the ketchup is validating correctly but it doesn't 'break' the malsup form process... if that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

some one over on experts exchange managed to solve this for me....

here is the final script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact_form').ketchup();
    $("input[type='submit']", "#contact_form").click(function(e) {
        if( $('#contact_form').ketchup("isValid") ) { 
            $('#contact_form').ajaxForm(function() { $('#form_content').html('thank you for filling the form'); });
        };
    });
});
```

this works perfectly :)